# issue with setting a private variable assigned in another class

Tags: java

heres the code block for my armors and weapons setting, but eclipse tells me that when I add to the variables for strength and hitpoints that it there is no variable assigned for it.  I assume this is because its a private variable in my player class, so do I make those variables public instead of private?

```
public void setArm(){
        switch
        (threeSidedDie.getValue()){
        case 1: Armors = "helmet";
            hitP += 1;
            break;
        case 2: Armors = "gloves";
            hitP += 2;
            break;
        case 3: Armors = "chest armor";
            hitP += 3;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use encapsulation: getters and/or setters.

Comment: You could make them public or package-private, or make getter/setter methods.

Comment: Note that private/protected/public is there to help _you_ (keep complexity down/exposure well defined). It's not a security thing.

Comment: Law of Demeter appliance: myPlayer.calculateHitPoints(...);  avoid getter and setter in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code. 
Use this in setArm:

```
myPlayer.getHitPoints()
```

Add something like this in your player class:

```
getHitPoints(){
    return this.hitPoints;
}
setHitPoints( int hitP ){
    this.hitPoints = hitP;
}
getStrength(){
    return this.strength;
}
setStrength( int str){
    this.strength = str;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have setters and getters. but I am storing the players in an array, the game asks the user how many players there are going to be and I need to make an array storing those players (havent figured that part out yet.)  how do I assign the weapon to a specific player?

Comment: Sounds like `.setArm()` should be a method be a method on player.

Comment: No, this is not complicated. Really, it just looks daunting. How are you writing the Java code? Are you using a development environment (IDE) like Eclipse?

Comment: yes I'm using eclipse, but my teacher hates eclipse and tried to get me to use jgrasp.  not nearly as useful.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to the Player class. Open the menu: Source and choose "Generate getters/setters" and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about [Feature Envy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/feature-envy) or [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)?

> Feature Envy: Methods that make extensive use of another class may belong in another
>   class. Consider moving this method to the class it is so envious of.

You should move your process mostly based on `player` values in the `player` class, resolving thus your problem and not involving ugly getters and setters.

Metaphor: If I need every day an a money transfer to my account, I have two choices:

1. Asking for all the data to the bank and prepare my transfer myself. Potentially error prone since I would be able to avoid any potential strict rules set by the bank.
2. I **tell** the bank employee:   "Please transfer this money to my account " (without needing to ask for any data !)

Obviously, 2) is logically advised.

**Asking is against the essence object-oriented programming. Telling/Sending messages is THE essence. In very rare cases, asking is needed.**

Good habits are taken since the first year ;)

Comment: no idea what that is.  I'm a first year (java 1) student.

Comment: He's saying "move .setArm() into your Player class", as I commented below.

Comment: +1 for a great and overlooked point. [Feature envy](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212128/what-is-a-feature-envy-code-and-why-is-it-considered-a-code-smell) is a code smell mistake that is common among novices